# How is this Pop-Up called and how do I implement it?

Tags: ios, swift, popup, storyboard

I've noticed some Apps of Apple Inc. implement this type of Pop-Up (see linked image). I tried to find it on the internet but without success.

Probably the name of it will be enough for me to implement it into my Storyboard-App, except I don't find a documentation online. So therefore a little explanation would be helpful.

[image]

Comment: It isn't an inbuilt control. You will need to create it yourself or find a library that does it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You create it from yourself programmatically, declare your containerView under your controller class, your descriptionLabel, your ImageView (in my case the button too):

```
let myButton: UIButton = {
    let b = UIButton()
    b.backgroundColor = .white
    b.setTitle("Tap Me!", for: .normal)
    b.setTitleColor(.black, for: .normal)
    b.titleLabel?.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 17, weight: .semibold)
    b.layer.cornerRadius = 20
    b.clipsToBounds = true
    b.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    
    return b
}()

let containerView: UIView = {
    let v = UIView()
    v.backgroundColor = .ultraDark // set your pop up backround color
    v.layer.cornerRadius = 18
    v.clipsToBounds = true
    v.alpha = 0
    v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    
    return v
}()

let myImageView: UIImageView = {
    let iv = UIImageView()
    iv.image = UIImage(systemName: "person.2.fill")?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)
    iv.tintColor = .gray
    iv.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
    iv.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    
    return iv
}()

let descriptionLabel: UILabel = {
    let l = UILabel()
    l.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return l
}()
```

Now in viewDidLoad set target and constraints:

```
view.backgroundColor = .black
    myButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(controlTextInTextfields), for: .touchUpInside)
    
    view.addSubview(myButton)
    myButton.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor, constant: -30).isActive = true
    myButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true
    myButton.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor, constant: 30).isActive = true
    myButton.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor, constant: -20).isActive = true
    
    view.addSubview(containerView)
    containerView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 230).isActive = true
    containerView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 220).isActive = true
    containerView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    containerView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
    
    containerView.addSubview(myImageView)
    myImageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.heightAnchor, multiplier: 0.8).isActive = true
    myImageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: myImageView.heightAnchor, constant: -20).isActive = true
    myImageView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    myImageView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.centerYAnchor, constant: -20).isActive = true
    
    containerView.addSubview(descriptionLabel)
    descriptionLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
    descriptionLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
    descriptionLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: myImageView.bottomAnchor, constant: -20).isActive = true
    descriptionLabel.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 20).isActive = true
```

Now write the func to show pop up and animate it (I added animation because it's cooler):

```
func savedPopUpView(myView: UIView, label: UILabel, labelText: String) {
    let savedLabel = label
    savedLabel.text = labelText
    savedLabel.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 18)
    savedLabel.textColor = .gray
    savedLabel.numberOfLines = 0
    savedLabel.textAlignment = .center
    myAnimation(myV: myView)
}

fileprivate func myAnimation(myV: UIView) {

    myV.alpha = 1
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        myV.layer.transform = CATransform3DMakeScale(0, 0, 0)
        
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 1, initialSpringVelocity: 1, options: .curveEaseOut, animations: {
            myV.layer.transform = CATransform3DMakeScale(1, 1, 1)
            
        }, completion: { (completed) in
            //completed
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2, delay: 2, usingSpringWithDamping: 1, initialSpringVelocity: 1, options: .curveEaseOut, animations: {
                myV.layer.transform = CATransform3DMakeScale(0.1, 0.1, 0.1)
                myV.alpha = 0
            })
        })
    }
}
```

How to use, call target button func like this:

```
@objc func controlTextInTextfields() {
    savedPopUpView(myView: containerView, label: descriptionLabel, labelText: "Tester: in entfernt")
}
```

In this case the pop up go away after 2 seconds, you can change this parameter depending on how you like best...

The result:

[image]